# jQuery sending event as parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to check the amount of typing characters in an input using `keyup` and `keydown`. 
I've done it earlier but not as separate function and it was a big mess in a code. I use 
`event` and when I did it without separate function everything worked great, but now I have a problem with send it through the functions. Maybe it's caused by totally wrong method to do this, so please give me some advice, how to do it properly.

This is my separate function:

```
function char_check($input_id, $div_id, $char_max, event)
{


    if(($char_max-$($input_id).val().length)<=0)
    {   
        var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
        if(key!=8)
        {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }


    if(($char_max-$($input_id).val().length)<0)
    {
        $($div_id).text("Your data will be cut short!");
    }
    else
    {
        $($div_id).text($char_max-$($input_id).val().length);
    }

}
```

And this is the way I call this function:

```
$('input[name=author]').keydown(function(e){

char_check($(this), "#chars_auth", 50, e);

});
```

Problem: Event doesn't work.

Comment: I cannot really see the issue here?!  Maybe making a jsfiddle.net would help illustrate your issue.

Comment: "I have a problem with send it through the functions". Event doesn't work.

Comment: ok -1 coming here from me.  Everything seems to work just fine.  Check your console http://jsfiddle.net/robschmuecker/wr4x6/

Comment: Miracle! Miracle! So that's the way, put your broken code into stackoverflow and it will work, dudes, now it works, it wasn't a joke!

Comment: Small suggestion.. You should always try to make every piece of code reusable, so it will not became "big mess". My suggestion is to just return number and display it in keydown listener. This way, you can use it also for other things. Or event better, add it to jquery. See: `$('#chars_auth').text($(this).getRemainingLength(e, 50));`

Comment: Check console log in the fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/bg4CE/1/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I understand it the code does not work, though I am not sure what does not work. Here are some suggestions. First I would create a function that builds your "check function". Something like:

```
var createCharCheck = function (div_id, char_max) {

  return function (event)  {
    if ((char_max - $(this).val().length) <= 0) {   
      var key = event.keyCode || event.charCode;
      if(key != 8) {
        event.preventDefault();
      }
    }

    if((char_max - $(this).val().length) < 0) {
      $(div_id).text("Your data will be cut short!");
    } else {
      $(div_id).text(char_max - $(this).val().length);
    }
  }

}

$('input[name=author]').keydown(createCharCheck('#chars_auth', 50));
```

This is not to be fancy, but save you some code and take advantage of closure. Now you have a function that you can use on any input. Hope this helps.